"Marginal" Three-Series Theorem?
Let $\{X_t\}_{t=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of random variables and define the partial sums by $S_t=\sum_{s=1}^t X_s$.
Kolmogorov's three-series theorem states that

Theorem (Davidson, 2021, Theorem 21.8): Let $\{X_t\}$ be an independent sequence. Then, $S_t$ converges almost surely if and only if there exists $a>0$ such that
$$\sum_{t=1}^\infty P(|X_t|>a)<\infty,$$
$$\sum_{t=1}^\infty\mathbb{E}[X_t 1\{|X_t|\leq a\}]<\infty,$$
$$\sum_{t=1}^\infty\text{Var}(X_t 1\{|X_t|\leq a\})<\infty.$$

Meanwhile, the conditional version of the theorem states that

Theorem (Hall and Heyde, 1980, Theorem 2.16): Here, $\{X_t\}$ can be an arbitrary sequence, but let $\{\mathcal{F}_t\}_{t=1}^\infty$ be an increasing sequence of $\sigma$-fields such that $S_t$ is $\mathcal{F}_t$-measurable. Then, $S_t$ converges almost surely if (but not only if) there exists $a>0$ such that
$$\sum_{t=1}^\infty P(|X_t|>a|\mathcal{F}_{t-1})<\infty\text{ a.s.},$$
$$\sum_{t=1}^\infty\mathbb{E}[X_t 1\{|X_t|\leq a\}|\mathcal{F}_{t-1}]<\infty\text{ a.s.},$$
$$\sum_{t=1}^\infty\text{Var}(X_t 1\{|X_t|\leq a\}|\mathcal{F}_{t-1})<\infty\text{ a.s.}$$

My question is: Can we replace the conditions of the latter theorem by the marginal ones as in the first theorem?
My reasoning is that, by the law of iterated expectations and the law of total variance,
$$\mathbb{E}\Biggl[\sum_{t=1}^\infty P(|X_t|>a|\mathcal{F}_{t-1})\Biggr]=\sum_{t=1}^\infty P(|X_t|>a),$$
$$\mathbb{E}\Biggl[\sum_{t=1}^\infty\mathbb{E}[X_t 1\{|X_t|\leq a\}|\mathcal{F}_{t-1}]\Biggr]=\sum_{t=1}^\infty\mathbb{E}[X_t 1\{|X_t|\leq a\}],$$
$$\mathbb{E}\Biggl[\sum_{t=1}^\infty\text{Var}(X_t 1\{|X_t|\leq a\}|\mathcal{F}_{t-1})\Biggr]\leq\sum_{t=1}^\infty\text{Var}(X_t 1\{|X_t|\leq a\}),$$
so if the right-hand sides are all finite, then the conditional series must be finite almost surely. But I could not find a textbook that says that independence can be lifted altogether for sufficiency, so I may be missing something. For example, Davidson (2021, p. 449) states that you can replace independence with martingale difference, but why only martingale difference?

Take $X_i = \frac X i$, where X is rademacher (anything bounded with mean 0 works).  The partial sums are always like log(n)

To set @mike's good example in context: the identity $\mathbb{E}\Biggl[\sum_{t=1}^\infty\mathbb{E}[X_t 1{|X_t|\leq a}|\mathcal{F}{t-1}]\Biggr]=\sum{t=1}^\infty\mathbb{E}[X_t 1{|X_t|\leq a}]$ is not true in this case (for every $a > 0$ and the only possible $\mathcal{F}_{t} = \sigma(X)$), so that's where your reasoning breaks down.

I see. Then if we have $\sum_{t=1}^\infty\mathbb{E}[X_t 1{|X_t|\leq a}|\mathcal{F}_{t-1}]<\infty$ a.s., we can maintain the conclusion of the theorem? Since both the probability and variance are nonnegative, I think it is safe to exchange the expectation and infinite summation for them, right?
